# facebook content looks diffrent in wall and home page , after posting the content from iOS app using facebook sdk of iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

Facebook content looks different in wall and home page , after posting the content from iOS app using facebook sdk of iOS,

Used Code : We are using following code for posting the data in facebook wall.

```
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         @"Found this app ", @"message",
         @"AppName", @"name",
       @"App Title", @"caption",
         @"Description data", @"description",
        @"Link URL", @"link",
         @"Image URL", @"picture",nil];
 // create the connection object.
        FBRequestConnection *newConnection = [[[FBRequestConnection alloc] initWithTimeout:kRequestTimeoutInterval] autorelease];

        // create the request object, using the fbid as the graph path as an alternative the request* static methods of the
        // FBRequest class could be used to fetch common requests, such as /me and /me/friends
        FBRequest *request=[[[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:activeSession
                                                     graphPath:@"me/feed"
                                                    parameters:params
                                                    HTTPMethod:@"POST"] autorelease];
```

Detail:  When we are going to post this data and link url ia available then content are looks different in home screen and profile screen .

Instead od App Name is display the Link URL title in home page but in profile page it display right content like App Title.
It happen only posting from iOS app , it looks good from Android app.

Please help Me tikamchandrakar@gmail.com or tikam.chandrakar@xymob.com
Let me know if any thing is not clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try This code. It works Perfect for me -

```
// Helper method to request publish permissions and post.
- (void)requestPermissionAndPost {

[FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                      defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                        if (!error && [FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] != NSNotFound) {

                                            // Now have the permission
                                            [self postOpenGraphAction];
                                        } else if (error){
                                            // Facebook SDK * error handling *
                                            // if the operation is not user cancelled
                                            if (error.fberrorCategory != FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
//                                                    [self presentAlertForError:error];
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }];
}

// Creates the Open Graph Action.
- (void)postOpenGraphAction {


NSString *pageId = @"";

if ([pageIdArray count] > 0) {
    pageId = [[pageIdArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"page_id"];
}else{
    pageId = @"";
}

//http://mistoh.com/mistohws/CategoriesIcon/CategoryIcon_%1$s.png

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                             parameters:@{
                                          @"link":@"http://mistoh.com/mistohws/CategoriesIcon/CategoryIcon_1.png",
                                          @"message":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just shared a Mistoh at %@",self.mistohNameStr],
                                          @"place":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",pageId],
                                          @"name":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.mistohNameStr],
                                          @"description":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.mistohDescStr],
                                          @"address":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.mistohAddressStr],
                                          @"tags":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.selectedFriendsStr]
                                          }
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          //verify result

                          if (!error) {

                              [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Shared Mistoh Successfully!!"
                                                          message:@""
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil]
                               show];

                          }else{
                              [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                          message:@"Error while sharing mistoh with friends."
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil]
                               show];

                              NSLog(@"Error : %@",[error description]);
                          }

                      }];

}
```

It looks good on facebook wall and timeline. Thank You..

Comment: I am getting following errorError Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0xceb9400 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 2500;
            message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}

Comment: Pass your parameters like above code. and this error occurs only because of give permissions.check your permission array.it will works fine.

Comment: How we can get permission? We are using below code which give me permission with posting the data . FBRequest *request=[[[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:GetAppDelegate().session
                                                     graphPath:@"me/feed"
                                                    parameters:params
                                                    HTTPMethod:@"POST"] autorelease];

Comment: I had try but getting error, Because i have already taken the permission. Please can you sent me some sample code for thatTerminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBSession: an attempt was made reauthorize permissions on an unopened session'

Comment: In your code Don't use NSMutableDictionary, instead of that use NSDictionary. and pass parameters like above code.may it will work.

Comment: Issue are still same ,

Comment: check your Bundle identifier for your project and you give Bundle identifier for your app which create on developer.facebook.com that they are same or not.